# curl submit basic auth and website user authentification in one command

Tags: linux, authentication, session, curl

I have a website dev.example.com that is protected with Basic Authentification.

I can get access to the website with permitting basic auth user and password like

```
https://ba_user:ba_pw@dev.example.com/
```

Now I'd also like to login as a website user (fe_user/fe_password) after passing the basic authentification.

Is there a way to submit the website user login data as well with the basic auth data? With

```
curl -u fe_user:fe_password https://ba_user:ba_pw@dev.example.com/import_log/1234/status
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your your site accepts user login credentials as basic authentication (`Authorization: Basic ...`), and that it supports multiple authorization headers:

```
basic_auth_header() 
{ 
    BASIC_AUTH=$(printf "%s:%s" "$1" "$2" | base64);
    echo "Authorization: Basic $BASIC_AUTH"
}

curl -H "$(basic_auth_header ba_user ba_pw)" -H "$(basic_auth_header fe_user fe_password)" https://dev.example.com/import_log/1234/status
```

That said, usually websites accept login credentials in access tokens (`Authorization: Bearer ...` headers), so `curl -u user:password ...` or `curl https://user:password@...` cannot be used to login to these sites.

If that's the case, then you need to figure out how to generate an access token from your login credentials and use:

```
curl -H Authorization: Bearer <access token> https://ba_user:ba_pw@dev.example.com/import_log/1234/status
```

---

You can test these situations as follows:

In one terminal window:

```
nc -l -p 50505
```

In another terminal window:

```
curl http://localhost:50505/
```

And here are some results:

```
curl http://localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl http://user1:password1@localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -u user1:password1 http://localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -u user1:password1 http://user1:password1@localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -u user2:password2 http://localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjI6cGFzc3dvcmQy
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -u user1:password1 http://user2:password2@localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -u user1:password1 -u user2:password2 http://localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjI6cGFzc3dvcmQy
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
```

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx' -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjI6cGFzc3dvcmQy' http://localhost:50505/
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50505
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQx
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjI6cGFzc3dvcmQy
```